# Why Kotlin can't choose which overloaded function to use?

Tags: kotlin

The code produces error, why?

Isn't `{ it }` equal to `{ v -> v }`?

```
fun <V, R> Iterable<V>.map(transform: (V) -> R): List<R> {
  return this.mapIndexed { i, v -> transform(v) }
}
fun <V, R> Iterable<V>.map(transform: (V, Int) -> R): List<R> {
  return this.mapIndexed { i, v -> transform(v, i) }
}

fun main() {
  val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
  println(list.map { v -> v }) // Works
  println(list.map { it })     // Fails
}
```

The error

```
Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference:
public fun <V, R> Iterable<Int>.map(transform: (Int) → ???): List<???> defined in root package in file test.kt
public fun <V, R> Iterable<Int>.map(transform: (Int, Int) → ???): List<???> defined in root package in file test.kt
```

Comment: It's probably just too many steps for the compiler to take to infer the type. There are various situations in Kotlin where the compiler can't figure something out not because it's logically impossible, but because the designers don't want compiling to take a long time. In this case, the compiler uses the lambda parameter to infer the type of V. But it also uses the lambda parameters to figure out the signature of the function. So maybe the compiler can't stack both of these pieces of logic at once on top of inferring an implicit parameter.